# Can we download a all chunks of m3u8 stream at once using javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, video, browser, m3u8

im having a website where i need to support download features in browser.

However, the video url is a stream url that returns m3u8

I dont have much knowledge in this file format, but if I understand correctly, it will break the video into multiple chunks and keep downloading the next chunk after finished

Now my question is

Is there any way we can write a script (that run in browsers) to download all chunks at once, and then concatenate them all to become a final video?

```
   fetch(
  'video link here',
)
  // Retrieve its body as ReadableStream
  .then(response => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    return new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        return pump();
        function pump() {
          return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
            // When no more data needs to be consumed, close the stream
            if (done) {
              controller.close();
              return;
            }
            // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
            controller.enqueue(value);
            return pump();
          });
        }
      },
    });
  })
  // Create a new response out of the stream
  .then(stream => new Response(stream))
  // Create an object URL for the response
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    console.log('finish downloading blob');
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = _filename;
    link.click();
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: It's literally a bunch of files. The main file contains a list of streams with their quality. Each of those stream files contain a list of chunks of the video. Beyond that, I'm not sure. I don't know how to stitch them together or convert them. As for actually downloading them, that might be a little tricky. Browsers typically prevent automated clicking if it doesn't somehow originate from a user action (a trusted event).

Comment: **(1)** M3U8 is just a text file. Use String functions to extract from it each separate link of the chunk file (not obvious if it is a `.ts` or `.m4s` or what file type). Use a function to download each chunk, running it as many times as needed. **(2)** Concatenation depends on if you know MP4 structure. Find out the video format inside your M3U8 file, then search Google for a Javascript `muxer` that can auto-convert into fragmented MP4 for you.